# Delete Rows in Excel Based on Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm close to figuring out the correct way to do this but I'm all searched out. I'm trying to search a column (Asset Tag) that holds various garbage but want to keep entire rows that start with AA as this confirms the row is actually an Asset Tag.

The code below gives me an "Object Required" error, and I believe I might not be correctly telling it to look at cell values with the"If rng.Cells(i) <> Left(cell.Value, 2) = "AA" Then" statement. Can someone point me in the right direction of what I need to do?

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Double, counter As Double
    Set rng = Range("C:C")
    i = 1
    For counter = 1 To rng.Rows.count
    If rng.Cells(i) <> Left(cell.Value, 2) = "AA" Then
        rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the "cell" object here `Left(cell.Value,2)`?

Comment: It would be a lot more efficient (which may be significant given your data size) to use a working column (either in VBA or manually), test for "AA", then use autofilter to delete the unwanted rows. Range loops are evil :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're deleting rows then you should always work from the bottom up:

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim counter As Long, numRows as long        

        With ActiveSheet
           Set rng = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("C:C"))
        End With
        numRows = rng.Rows.Count

        For counter = numRows to 1 Step -1 
         If Not rng.Cells(counter) Like "AA*" Then
            rng.Cells(counter).EntireRow.Delete
         End If
       Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I was wondering if bottom up made more sense. I tried so many ways just to get SOMETHING to happen. After about 5 minutes of running that macro it worked perfectly =) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Given your code took 5 minutes I suggest you try this AutoFilter approach. It uses a working column (the first unused column part the usedrange) to run a case sensitive text for the first two letters of column C cells being "AA". If not an autofilter deletes these rows.

```
    Sub KillnonAA()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'in case the sheet is blank
    On Error Resume Next
    lRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    lCol = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
    If lRow = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lCol + 1), ws.Cells(lRow, lCol + 1))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Rows(1).Insert
    With rng1.Offset(0, 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=EXACT(LEFT(RC3,2),""AA"")"
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="FALSE"
        .EntireRow.Delete
        'in case all records were deleted
        On Error Resume Next
        .EntireColumn.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```