# Moving rows based on column values

Tags: excel, vba, rows, paste

I need to scan through all of the rows in the "Master" worksheet, find any cells with the value "Shipped" in the column "Status", then cut and paste each entire row to another sheet. The pasted rows need to be placed after the last row also.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760439/delete-rows-in-excel-based-on-criteria) post (pasted below) which I slightly modified to delete rows successfully. But I can not figure out how to move rows instead. Should I try an entirely new method?

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim counter As Long, numRows as long        

        With ActiveSheet
           Set rng = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("C:C"))
        End With
        numRows = rng.Rows.Count

        For counter = numRows to 1 Step -1 
         If Not rng.Cells(counter) Like "AA*" Then
            rng.Cells(counter).EntireRow.Delete
         End If
       Next

End Sub
```

I do not know VBA. I only kind of understand it because of my brief programming history. I hope that is okay and thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up combining the code I was originally  using ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760439/delete-rows-in-excel-based-on-criteria)) with an AutoFilter macro ([found here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/612848-visual-basic-applications-copy-row-another-sheet-matching-criteria.html)). This is probably not the most efficient way but it works for now. If anyone knows how I can use only the For Loop or only the AutoFilter method that would be great. Here is my code. Any edits I should make?

```
Sub DeleteShipped()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim counter As Long, numRows As Long

    With Sheets("Master")

        'Check for any rows with shipped
        If .Range("R:R").Find("Shipped", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No shipped plates found. ", , "No Rows Moved": Exit Sub
        Else

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            'Copy and paste rows
            lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            lastrow2 = Worksheets("ShippedBackup").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A1:U" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=18, Criteria1:="Shipped"
            .Range("A2:U" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("ShippedBackup").Range("A" & lastrow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
            .ShowAllData

            'Delete rows with shipped status
            Set rng = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("R:R"))
            numRows = rng.Rows.Count

            For counter = numRows To 1 Step -1
             If rng.Cells(counter) Like "Shipped" Then
                rng.Cells(counter).EntireRow.Delete
             End If
            Next

            MsgBox "All shipped records have been moved to the ""ShippedBackup"" worksheet.", , "Backup Complete"

        End If
End With
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways you could do it, can you add a filter to the top columns, filter by the value of 'Shipped'?  Does it need to be copy and pasted into a new sheet?

It's not the most concise code but it might work

```
    sub Shipped_filter()
dim wsSheet as worksheet
dim wsOutputSheet as worksheet
dim BottomRow as integer

Set wsSheet = worksheets("Sheet1") 'change to the sheet name
set wsOutputSheet = worksheets("Sheet2") 'change to the sheet name

'*****************************
'* Delete old data on Sheet2 *
'*****************************
wsoutputsheet.activate
Activesheet.cells.clearall

wsSheet.range("A1").select
selection.autofilter

BottomRow = wsSheet.range("A90000").end(xlup).row ' or another column you guarantee will always have a value

activesheet.range("$A$1:$Z$"&BottomRow).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Shipped" ' change field to whatever column number Status is in

'********************************
'* Error trap in case no update *
'********************************

if activesheet.range("A90000").end(xlup).row = 1 then
 msgbox("Nothing to ship")
exit sub
end if


wsSheet.range("A1:Z"&Bottomrow).select
selection.copy

wsOutputSheet.range("A1").select
selection.pastespecial Paste:=xlpastevalues
application.cutcopymode = false

msgbox('update complete')

end sub
```

I haven't tried it so it might need updating

Comment: Yes a filter can be added. I would prefer to cut & paste if it's possible because then I do not have to delete the rows after. I'll try the code now and report back. Thanks!

Comment: I ran into three separate errors. Thanks to you I now understand how AutoFilter and I was able to find other code to edit. I'll post my answer in a bit. It probably isn't the best lol